# Can you identify this algorithm?

Tags: xor

We are attempting to integrate our application in to a third party system. To do this we need to pass encrypted passwords in to this system. I have decompiled the assembly and looking at the code it seems that they are using something similar to XOR encryption (In a production system...) From what I can see from the decompiled code it does something like this:

The pseudo code bellow is wrong. Here is a link to the source code, decompiled , converted to C# and cleaned up a bit: http://pastebin.com/rAcXPvL6

```
string key = "1234567890123456"
string plainText = "test"
int[] keyData = GetAsciiValuesAsArray(key)
int[] plainData = GetAsciiValuesAsArray(plainText)
int prime = GeneratePrimeNumber()
string cipherText = ""


foreach(plainTextChar in plainData)
{
     int a = prime / 256.0 * 256.0 - prime % 256 / 256.0
     int b = prime % 256
     for(int i = 0; i < 16;i++)
     {
          keyData[i] = keyData[i] ^ GetAsciiValue(plainTextChar);
     }
     plainTextChar = plainTextChar ^ (a ^ b)
     int c = (plainTextChar / 16.0 * 16.0 - (plainTextChar % 16)) / 16.0;
     int d = plainTextChar = % 16
     cipherText = cipherText + ConvertFromAscii(c + 97) + ConvertFromAscii(d + 97)
}
```

Does this seem familiar to anyone? Hopefully it's a recognized algorithm and not something they have cobbled together themselves.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Your decompilation seems wrong.  Calculation for a and c look incorrect, and keyData doesn't seem to ever be used.  The ciphertext isn't dependent on anything in the key, only on the value of the prime.  Why is GetAsciiValue being used on plainTextChar?

Comment: Hmm, I'll review it and post the decompiled source - but its messy

Comment: Your right - there is an extra method. See question for full source

Comment: The use of floating point arithmetic looks just wrong. My guess is that it doesn't work.

Comment: It definitely converts plain text in to something in a reproducible way, as for what that something is meant to be or whether its correct, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Analyzing code is off-topic on this site, don't expect much.

To the question: "Never write your own crypto" is a statement, that is all too often disregarded. Without digging deep, it looks like some self-made (and totally insecure) algorithm: The key is not used at all, therefore it is basically a streamcipher (one symbol at a time) with a deterministic keystream.

Recommendation: Do not use this, and don't use their crypto implementations in the future. Not every error is as easy to detect as this one. And in crypto you can do lots of things wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. sadly we have to use it. If I had it my way we would use  SHA512, not reversible encryption.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using this. In a commercial application, this is a huge financial risk. The effort to break this is practically close to zero. Basically, this could be a backdoor to the entire system. And on a scale I would rate it much, much worse than bad (none) password policies.